# How to connect Azure SQL DW Server using proxy details in pyodbc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I want to connect to Azure SQL DW instance using proxy details as firewall is blocking to establish the connection to Azure SQL DW.

below are the code to connect SQL DW from pyodbc:

```
pyodbc.connect("DSN="+DW_dsn+";UID="+DW_db_usr+";PWD="+DW_db_pwd , autocommit=True);
```

How can I add proxy to it?

**python version**:- 3.6

**pyodbc version**:- 4.x

**ODBC drive**r:- Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server